# Error says "Import in body of module; reorder to top import/first"

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnWWi.png)I don't know why I'm getting these error called "Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first" although I have written the code on correct sequence.[Error [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhdu.png)

`import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';`
`const SCROLL_UP = 'up';`
`const SCROLL_DOWN = 'down';`
`const useScrollDirection = ({ initialDirection, thresholdPixels, off } = {}) => { const [scrollDir, setScrollDir] = useState(initialDirection);`

Comment: Kindly Read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You should check that only your import statements are at the top of the file.

then place the constants in the function.

```js
const useScrollDirection = ({ initialDirection, thresholdPixels, off } = {}) => { 
   const SCROLL_UP = 'up'; 
   const SCROLL_DOWN = 'down'; 
   const [scrollDir, setScrollDir] = useState(initialDirection);
}
```